# Android Studio : not using latest build tools

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin

Everything is updated but Android Studio not using latest build tools. 
Here is the error:(I tested by changing those version codes from 26 to 27 and other version available on my skd folder (even with extension like 27.0.2) and added build tools string, below compileSdkVersion there but did not work.)
[image]

Here the tools are installed: (Installed Build-tools version 27.0.2)
[image]

Only know this as it is shown on message window but don't know if using any other components version of a lower version code.

(Also using gradle4.4)

**Where can I change these version codes that will take effect?
What is wrong here?/What are the possible causes?**

Note: I know I can just click that link and probably get the issue solved but that is a lower version code than I have and willing to use.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: seems like your vesion are update till marsmellow. as you can see there is an update available. update them and you will have upto date versions. rest is you change your versions in android gradle file,.

Comment: just click on error that is coming below and let it download then it will work.

Comment: The update is 27.0.3 and I have 27.0.2 :) @ umair

Comment: Thanks, but I stated this too "I know I can just click that link and probably get the issue solved but that is a lower version code than I have and willing to use" @Shivam

Comment: change your compile sdk version to 27.0.2

Comment: @Rifat change your gradle file like I suggested in my answer and then check if it works or not.

Comment: @Rifat check my answer and change gradle as you willing to use latest version.let me know if it works or not

Comment: Thanks a lot your answers helped me.

Comment: @Rifat if our answers help you please upvote them and accept them :)

Comment: It will be beneficial if I know - how to make this change permanent/automatic for future builds.

Comment: @Rifat yes for starters always use latest build tools for your project development and whenever you create a project you specify the oldest version to supp, in this way gradle picks up the oldest and latest versions and compile your project accordingly. What you missed was you were not giving buildToolsVersions in your project's gradle file. that's why it was unable to find the tools you mentioned to build the project.

Comment: @Rifat Happy to help you. If it worked than you can accept my answer so it can help others.

Answer (score 1):

For starters always use latest build tools for your project development and whenever you create a project you specify the oldest version to supp, in this way **gradle** picks up the oldest and latest versions and compile your project accordingly. What you missed was you were not giving `buildToolsVersions` in your project's **gradle** file. that's why it was unable to find the tools you mentioned to build the project.Change your **gradle** file like this and it should work then:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "Your app ID"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
lintOptions{
    abortOnError false
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

here is my app level gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'

}
```

and here is my project level gradle

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and here is my **gradle-wrapper.properties**
[image]

Change gradle to 4.1 as shown in image.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line below compileSdkVersion

buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"